# Click button to draw text won't work unless frame is resized

Tags: java, swing, graphics

If in the code below if I leave out the boolean variable bDrawText then the text shows up as soon as the program is launched.
So I set that variable to false so as to have the text drawn only when I click the button. But it does not work and the text apperars only if the frame is resized. I assume my use of graphics is wrong...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Demo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                justAnyFrame f = new justAnyFrame("Draw text",200,100,600,400);                         
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);       
            }
        });
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class justAnyFrame extends JFrame { 
    private JButton bDrawText;
    private boolean drawNow=false;
    public justAnyFrame(String title,int left,int top,int width,int height) {   
        setTitle(title);
        setLocation(left,top);
        setSize(width,height);
        centralPanel cp=new centralPanel();
        cp.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        add(cp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        lowerPanel lp=new lowerPanel();
        add (lp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);       
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class lowerPanel extends JPanel  implements ActionListener {
        public lowerPanel() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            bDrawText=new JButton("Draw Text");
            bDrawText.addActionListener(this);  
            add(bDrawText);
        }
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object clicked=e.getSource();
            if(clicked==bDrawText) {
                drawNow=true;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class centralPanel extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
            if(drawNow) {
                g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                Font myFont=new Font("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,40);
                g2.setFont(myFont);
                g2.drawString("QWERTY",50,100);
            }
        }           
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call repaint for the lowerPanel, but it is necessary to repaint the centralPanel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, it now works after I've declared the centralPanel cp as private outside the frame constructor and then called cp.repaint(); from the button's actionPerformed method.

Comment: Good call on deleting that other answer, and on expanding this one. Keep going like that and you'll soon have enough rep to make comments. :)